# Paperclip triggers validation error on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have this function in my Paperclip model :

```
def ratiocorrect
    ratio = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original].path).width / Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original].path).height
    if ratio < 1.499 or ratio > 1.501
      errors.add(:image,'ratio should be 4:3')
    end
  end
```

It checks if an image has a ratio of 3:2 before saving it.

I enforce this with :

```
validate :ratiocorrect
```

And it works flawlessly.

Though when I want to destroy an image I get the following error:

```
undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
ratio = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original].path).width / Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original].path).height
```

It seems it is checking against a `queued_for_write` image again, as there is none for destroy action.

Is it possible to validate only when created or updated, not destroyed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, use the `:create` and/or `:update` options with your custom validation.

You will do something like this:

```
validate :ratiocorrect, on: :create
```

> By default, such validations will run every time you call valid? or save the object. But it is also possible to control when to run these custom validations by giving an :on option to the validate method, with either: :create or :update.

Check out [Custom Methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) for additional information.